# Using WhatsApp on emulator, how to scan the QR for WhatsApp web?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, android-emulator, bluestacks

I am using WhatsApp on a laptop with BlueStacks (Android emulator), and I cannot scan the QR code. I don't have any Android phones.

How can I link my WhatsApp profile with WhatsApp web?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it via downloading LDPlayer. It has a built-in feature which gives you a small screen to drag to where the QR code is on the screen

To avail of the feature, just click the link device on the emulator WhatsApp and choose the "capture screen" option, not the "camera" option on the right. It will simply give you a screen to drag to anywhere on the screen where the QR code is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a camera. Try with an external webcam installed on the PC.
Or hope some root programmer shell guide. Keep on googling.

Answer (score 0):

How to scan QR code in the same PC using WhatsApp and BlueStacks:

1. Open WhatsApp web from where to scan the QR code in half window
2. Also, open BlueStack in half window
3. Click on WhatsApp web from BlueStacks' WhatsApp
4. Take a mirror and wait until the scan is completed

Enjoy if you have no smartphone but you have a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

First, open WhatsApp on BlueStacks and ensure it is minimized so that it doesn't occupy the entire screen. Next, open WhatsApp Web on Chrome, which will display the QR code. Again, minimize the Chrome window to make both BlueStacks and Chrome visible simultaneously on the screen. Now, using a mirror, position it in such a way that it reflects the QR code from the Chrome window onto the WhatsApp window within BlueStacks. Focus on the reflected QR code within BlueStacks, and it should scan successfully.